# Executing javascript after loading different site

Tags: web-applications, cross-domain, javascript, yql

I need to write a webapp, that will check if site contains an element (e.g div with id="iamhere"). This site can be any site, it's not in the same domain that my script is. I thought about doing something like:

1. Go to my site, load javascript library.
2. Load the other site.
3. Execute my function.

This seems to be impossible - am I right (script execution stops after window.location.assign() and there's no way to "bind" a script tag to site's DOM)?
Does anybody has an idea, how to make it work? I know I could use yql, but maybe there's better solution.

Comment: Sounds like it's not possible for obvious security reasons.

Comment: @Haochi: yes, it's seems to be impossible without script as proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Check out JavaScript's [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function.  You can periodically check the readiness of whatever with something like this:

```
function checkReadyState() 
{
  if (somethingIsReady)  {
    doStuffWhenReady();
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(function() { checkReadyState(); }, 200);   //Waits 200 milliseconds and calls checkReadyState() again.
  }
}
```

Comment: Timeouts don't fire after the page has changed.

Comment: He's talking about loading another site's page - so I assume it's within an iframe or something.

Comment: It could be in an iframe, but modifying iframe contents is forbidden in most (every?) browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fetch the site with a scripting language to act as a proxy. I'll use PHP in this example:

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');

echo $file;

?>
```

When necessary to populate the div - you can do so with your javascript.  If you're using jQuery it would look something like this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#amihere').load('myphpproxyfile.php');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use YQL.

Replace the last 2 query string parameters and check the json result.

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url=@url%20and%20xpath=@xpathformat=json&callback=cvfunc&url=<your-url>&xpath=<your-xpath>
```

Example:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&callback=cbfunc&url=http://www.stackoverflow.com&xpath=//div[@id=%27header%27]&q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url=@url%20and%20xpath=@xpath
```